# How to use export variable from bash script in expect script?

Tags: bash, expect

I have this script which is a combination of bash and expect script.

```````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````
#!/bin/bash
#!/usr/bin/expect

export TART="4 5 8 9"

for i in "$@"; do
        echo "Tart #: $i"

        case "$i" in

                1)
                IP=10.171.0.10
                ;;
                2)
                IP=10.171.0.11
                ;;
                3)
                IP=10.171.0.12
                ;;
                4)
                IP=10.171.0.13
                ;;
                5)
                IP=10.171.0.14
                ;;
                8)
                IP=10.171.0.17
                ;;
                9)
                IP=10.171.0.18
                ;;
                *)
                echo "Invalid TARTS '$i'" >&2;
                exit 1
                ;;
        esac

        echo "    ----  Launching Tart $i  ----  "
                sshpass -p "tart123" ssh -Y -X -L 5900:$IP:5901 tarts@$IP <<EOF
                  export DISPLAY=:1
                gnome-terminal -e "bash -c \"pwd; cd /home/tarts; pwd; ./launch_tarts.sh exec bash\""
                exit
EOF
done

/usr/bin/expect << 'EOF'

set tart_num $env(TART)

puts "Tarts to be updated: $tart_num"

for { set index 0 } { $index < [llength $tart_num] } { incr index } {
 puts "In Loop: $index"
 puts "Tart Num: [lindex $tart_num $index]"

switch -- [lindex $tart_num $index]\
4 {
        spawn telnet 10.171.0.13 6187
        set timeout -1
} 5 {
        spawn telnet 10.171.0.14 6187
        set timeout -1
} 8 {
        spawn telnet 10.171.0.17 6187
        set timeout -1
} 9 {
        spawn telnet 10.171.0.18 6187
        set timeout -1
}
        expect {
                "*traffic*" {
                puts "``````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````"
                puts "Registering Group1, Group2"
                send "traffic map rate reg_group1 0\r"
                send "traffic map rate reg_group2 0\r"

                puts "wait 2 seconds .."
                send "traffic go\r"
                sleep 2

                puts "wait 3 seconds"
                sleep 3

                send -- "^]"
                expect -exact "^\]\rtelnet> "
                send -- "close\r"
                expect eof
        }
}
EOF
```````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````

Can someone please guide me how can I use the export variable such that I can use any of the case from the variable. Right now when I run the script it starts working on all the cases like "4 5 8 9" but I want to be able to use any one of the values. Can someone please guide?

Comment: Don't recreate code you wrote in the shell. `export IP` before calling expect, and in expect use `spawn telnet $env(IP) 6187`

Comment: I am asking for export Tart="8 9 10 11". When I run it always runs the job for the four cases. Is there a way I could run a job on any indiviual number?

Comment: @glennjackman You had asked me to try out your code rewrite but its not working and when I run it I get an error which says "Invalid TART" as it runs into the if condition.
Just to let you know what my script was doing so that maybe you can help. The above script which I had created was launching TARTS VMs now TARTS are basically call simulation tools and I am simply launching TARTS and once launched then the expect part starts where stations register. The problem I was facing was that it was being done sequentially like for the above script its doing for 4, 5, 8, 9 and in that order.

Comment: What I want to be able to do is I want to do it any order and I want to be able to do it in parallel. Lastly I want to give the TARTS VM number in command line argument so that I can use any of the numbers I want to use.

Comment: Well, you'll have to show the problematic code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider this rewrite:

```````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````sh
#!/bin/bash
#!/usr/bin/expect

ips=(
    [1]=10.171.0.10
    [2]=10.171.0.11
    [3]=10.171.0.12
    [4]=10.171.0.13
    [5]=10.171.0.14
    [8]=10.171.0.17
    [9]=10.171.0.18
)
export TART="4 5 8 9"

ip=()
for i in $TART; do
    if [[ ! -v ips[i] ]]; then
        echo "Invalid TARTS '$i'" >&2;
        exit 1
    fi
    ip+=(${ips[i]})

    echo "    ----  Launching Tart $i  ----  "
    sshpass -p "tart123" ssh -Y -X -L "5900:${ips[i]}:5901" tarts@"${ips[i]}" <<EOF1
        export DISPLAY=:1
        gnome-terminal -e 'bash -c "pwd; cd /home/tarts; pwd; ./launch_tarts.sh exec bash"'
        exit
EOF1

done
export IP="${ip[*]}"

/usr/bin/expect << 'EOF2'

    set tarts [split $env(TART)]
    set ips   [split $env(IP)]

    puts "Tarts to be updated: $tarts"

    for {set index 0} {$index < [llength $tarts]} {incr index} {
        puts "In Loop: $index"
        set tart [lindex $tarts $index]
        puts "Tart Num: $tart"
        set ip [lindex $ips $index]
        puts "IP: $ip"

        set timeout -1

        spawn telnet $ip 6187
        expect {
            "*traffic*" {
                puts "``````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````"
                puts "Registering Group1, Group2"
                send "traffic map rate reg_group1 0\r"
                send "traffic map rate reg_group2 0\r"

                puts "wait 2 seconds .."
                send "traffic go\r"
                sleep 2

                puts "wait 3 seconds"
                sleep 3

                send -- "^]"
                expect -exact "^\]\rtelnet> "
                send -- "close\r"
                expect eof
            }
        }
    }
EOF2
```````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````

Comment: Glenn I have tried this solution but its not working. I replaced $TART with $ips to loop over IP addresses and the IP variable is not picking any value.

Comment: When I use $TART in for loop it goes into Invalid tart condition.

Comment: To loop over all the IP addresses: `for x in "${ips[@]}"` with the quotes. Otherwise, show exactly the code and describe exactly what happens.

Comment: Thanks Glenn, although its been a long time but your answer really helped. Thanks for the guidance.